# /var/lib/tor cannot be read: Permission denied or Couldn't create private data directory

Tags: tor, google-cloud-shell

I use google cloud shell to execute this program

1. Linux version

> ```
>     Distributor ID: Debian
>     Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
>     Release:        10
>     Codename:       buster
> ```

2. Tor version 0.3.5.10.
3. When I tried restarting "**sudo service tor restart**" Tor I received an error

```
[ ok ] Stopping tor daemon...done (not running - there is no /run/tor/tor.pid).
[....] Starting tor daemon...Jun 27 01:51:04.132 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor cannot be read: Permission denied
Jun 27 01:51:04.132 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't create private data directory "/var/lib/tor"
Jun 27 01:51:04.132 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
failed.
```

4. So I set full permissions for the tor directory **sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/tor**

   ```
   [FAIL] Checking if tor configuration is valid ... failed!
    Jun 27 01:53:59.685 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1g, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.3.8.
    Jun 27 01:53:59.685 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
    Jun 27 01:53:59.685 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
    Jun 27 01:53:59.685 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
    Jun 27 01:53:59.688 [warn] Error setting groups to gid 114: "Operation not permitted".
    Jun 27 01:53:59.688 [warn] If you set the "User" option, you must start Tor as root.
    Jun 27 01:53:59.688 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Problem with User value. See logs for details.
    Jun 27 01:53:59.688 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
   ```
5. I use root privileges **sudo su**

   [ ok ] Stopping tor daemon...done (not running - there is no /run/tor/tor.pid).
   [....] Starting tor daemon...Jun 27 01:58:58.455 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor cannot be read: Permission denied
   Jun 27 01:58:58.455 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't create private data directory "/var/lib/tor"
   Jun 27 01:58:58.455 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

***Is there any way that can help me solve my problem or how can i be able to install tor version 2.9.14?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have already solved the problem by now, if not I hope this can help.

---

***Is there any way that can help me solve my problem?***

**OPTION 1**

Let's take a look at these warnings:

```
[warn] Error setting groups to gid 114: "Operation not permitted".
[warn] If you set the "User" option, you must start Tor as root.
[warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Problem with User value.
```

To get a log of all users run `cat /etc/passwd` and you'll see `debian-tor` listed:

```
...
debian-tor:x:108:114::/var/lib/tor:/bin/false
...
```

The folder `/var/lib/tor` is owned by user `debian-tor`, so `sudo -u debian-tor tor` will work.

Alternatively, you can run this for your current user: (or `chmod 777` for all)

```
chmod 700 -R /var/lib/tor/*
chown -R tor /var/lib/tor/
sudo service tor restart
```

You actually should run tor as non-root, else you get this message:

```
You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
```

**OPTION 2**

As the warning suggests to `see logs for details` you should check for a message within `dsmeg` and `/var/log/syslog`. If you find anything then it can be AppArmor or SELinux blocking tor. Both SELinux and AppArmor provide a set of tools to isolate applications from each other to protect the host system from being compromised, so it's not recommended disabling them permanently but temporarily for debugging.

According to [Debian SELinux support](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux#:%7E:text=Debian%20SELinux%20support,it%2C%20see%20the%20Setup%20Notes.):

> The Debian packaged Linux kernels have SELinux support compiled in,
> but disabled by default.

Check the SELinux state with [`getenforce`](https://www.strongdm.com/docs/architecture/deployment/selinux), if the output is Permissive or Disabled then you're set.

Moreover, looking at [AppArmor/Progress](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/Progress#Done_.28for_Buster.2C_at_least.29):

> Since Debian 10 (Buster), AppArmor is enabled by default.

To disable AppArmor on your system run: ([reference](https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse#Disable_AppArmor))

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/default/grub.d
echo 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT apparmor=0"' \
| sudo tee /etc/default/grub.d/apparmor.cfg
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

There's a chance that either one's the culprit. Users have reported similar issue [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/tor-permission-error).

---

***How can i be able to install tor version 2.9.14?***

Downgrading the tor package is as simple as this:

```
sudo apt-get install tor=0.2.9.14
```

But why would you want do that?

tor v2 will be [deprecated](https://blog.torproject.org/v2-deprecation-timeline) soon. You'll see warnings like:

```
[warn] At least one protocol listed as required in the consensus is
not supported by this version of Tor. You should upgrade. This version
of Tor will not work as a client on the Tor network. The missing
protocols are: DirCache=2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4 Link=4-5
```

---

**NB**: Post on [tor.stackexchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/) for tor related issues.

Comment: Awesome, I looked for quite a few posts, and this allowed me to start tor without sudo rights:
```
sudo chmod 700 -R /var/lib/tor/*
sudo chown -R myusername /var/lib/tor/
sudo service tor restart
```